# Parallel foreach with two arguments

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I have this code:

```
  library(doParallel)
    registerDoParallel(cores = 8)

    result = foreach(A = c(1, 2, 3),B = c(10, 20), .combine = list) %dopar% {
    A*B
}
```

result

```
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 40
```

but I want:
10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 60

Comment: `foreach(A = c(1, 2, 3))%:%foreach(B = c(10, 20), .combine = cbind)%dopar%{A*B}`

Comment: As a side note, I came here trying to figure out out to have a `foreach` loop where one loop was dependent on the first in such a way that the outer loop wouldn't have to wait for the inner loop to finish.  @Khashaa 's construct works for this as illustrated:  `foreach(A = c(1, 2, 3))%:%foreach(B = c(A, 20), .combine = cbind)%dopar%{c(A,B)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in `A` and `B` are iterators that advance in parallel. This is not a nested loop. In such a `foreach` construction, after each iteration the next value of the sequence `A` *and* the next value of the sequence `B` is selected, until the end of any one of the sequences is reached. A not particularly elegant workaround consists in substantially increasing the size of the sequences `A` and `B` in an ordered way, like this:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 8)
result <- foreach( A =rep(c(1,2,3),2), B = rep(c(10, 20), each=3), 
                  .combine='cbind') %dopar% { A*B }
#> result
#     result.1 result.2 result.3 result.4 result.5 result.6
#[1,]       10       20       30       20       40       60
```

There are certainly better ways to solve the problem, but this might be helpful to illustrate why you obtained an unexpected result. In any case I hope this helps.